# Laravel spatie/laravel-permission @can directive

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I'm currently working with Spatie roles and permissions library.
I have multiple guards which are admin and web. My admin have permission to 'manage authentication' with guard_name = admin.
When I try to run the syntax below it return true.

```
current_user()->hasPermissionTo('manage authentication', 'admin')
```

But when I use @can directives the span tag not appear.

```
@can('manage authentication')
<span>Hello</span>
@endcan
```

I tried this, but still the span tag is not appearing.

```
@can('manage authentication', 'admin')
<span>Hello</span>
@endcan
```

Am I doing it wrongly?

Update:
I dont have any roles / permission related property and function inside my user model

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` will work or you need to deleted any folder in `storage/framework/cache` manually

Comment: @sta thanks for replying, I just tried php artisan cache:clear and the span tag still not showing

Comment: Delete everything from `/storage/framework/cache/`

Comment: @sta tried removing folder inside cache still not working

Answer (score 5):

@can not will work with multi guards

You can use this :

```
@if(auth('guard-name')->check() && auth('guard-name')->user()->can('permission-name'))
```

after that run :

```
php artisan cache:forget spatie.permission.cache
```

then :

```
php artisan cache:clear
```